# Mysql failed with symlink log folder

Tags: 22.04, mysql, log

I'm trying to move /var/log to a /home/shared/var/log using a symlink, the problem is that mysql crashes.

Here is the process:

```
service rsyslog stop

mv /var/log/ /home/shared/var

ln -s /home/shared/var/log /var/log

service rsyslog stop
```

mysql - status

```
 mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-10-24 10:10:51 UTC; 1h 24min ago
 Process: 1167 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 Process: 1180 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1180 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Status: "Server shutdown complete"
 Error: 9 (Bad file descriptor)
 CPU: 154ms
```

Some logs from syslog

```
 Oct 24 09:49:45 alfa kernel: [  861.500725] audit: type=1400 audit(1666604985.104:34): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=89994 comm="apparmor_parser"
 Oct 24 10:10:45 alfa kernel: [    8.026192] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606245.678:39): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=740 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:45 alfa kernel: [    8.026341] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606245.678:40): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=740 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:45 alfa kernel: [    8.026463] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606245.678:41): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=740 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:45 alfa kernel: [    8.026515] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606245.678:42): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=740 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:45 alfa kernel: [    8.026561] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606245.678:43): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=740 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:45 alfa kernel: [    8.026604] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606245.678:44): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=740 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:45 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Oct 24 10:10:45 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Oct 24 10:10:46 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
 Oct 24 10:10:47 alfa kernel: [    9.533830] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606247.186:45): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=965 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:47 alfa kernel: [    9.541263] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606247.194:46): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=965 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:47 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Oct 24 10:10:47 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Oct 24 10:10:47 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
 Oct 24 10:10:48 alfa kernel: [   10.915630] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606248.566:51): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=1033 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:48 alfa kernel: [   10.934619] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606248.586:52): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=1033 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:48 alfa kernel: [   10.934797] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606248.586:53): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=1033 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:48 alfa kernel: [   10.934879] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606248.586:54): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=1033 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:48 alfa kernel: [   10.934922] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606248.586:55): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=1033 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:48 alfa kernel: [   10.934962] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606248.586:56): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=1033 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:48 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Oct 24 10:10:48 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Oct 24 10:10:49 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
 Oct 24 10:10:49 alfa kernel: [   12.223305] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606249.874:57): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=1118 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:49 alfa kernel: [   12.237295] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606249.890:58): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=1118 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:49 alfa kernel: [   12.237467] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606249.890:59): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=1118 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:49 alfa kernel: [   12.237537] audit: type=1400 audit(1666606249.890:60): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/shared/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=1118 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=114 ouid=114
 Oct 24 10:10:49 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Oct 24 10:10:49 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Oct 24 10:10:50 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
 Oct 24 10:10:51 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Oct 24 10:10:51 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Oct 24 10:10:51 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
 Oct 24 10:10:51 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
 Oct 24 10:10:51 alfa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.g
```

Comment: What are the permissions on that directory? MySQL demands that its logging directory be have its owner and group set as `mysql:adm`. The permissions will also need to be set as `750`. I've not used symlinked directories for logging but, if MySQL continues to refuse to use the directory, you may need to edit the appropriate `my.cnf` file to specify the full path where the logs are to be written.